# SwiftUI align SF Symbol as text with a text

Tags: image, text, swiftui, alignment

I need to display a SF Symbol (image) and a text in a view (as a title). As the text could be quite long, I want that it passes under the image for second line.

Expected result (almost!):

[image]

I first tried a `HStack` with image and text. But text doesn't go under image: Second line starts with a left 'padding' (corresponding to left image space).

So I did this code (to get previous screenshot):

```swift
HStack(alignment:.top) {
    Text(Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle"))
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundColor(.pink)
    +
    Text("A long text as example")
        .font(.title2).bold()
        .foregroundColor(.pink)
}
.frame(width:140)
```

But I want to align image with center of first line. Center of image should be vertically in middle of top of `A` and bottom of `g`.

It is important that my second (and more) line passes under my image. And I don't want a bigger font for image.

Comment: Did you tried to add the image inside the text ? This can be done in SwiftUI: Text(Image(…)+Text(…))

Comment: Yes I did. Look my code there is the `+` to join both texts.

Comment: Not exactly . I said : Text ( Image + Text ) .

Comment: It is almost ok: image is aligned to text. But image has not same font as rest of text and with your solution it does. I want a smaller image than text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t know if you can force the image to automatically be centred in all cases, but you can add a `.baselineOffset()` modifier to the image-in-text to shift the image upwards by a fixed amount. For example:

```
Text(Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle"))
  .font(.caption)
  .foregroundColor(.pink)
  .baselineOffset(3.0)
+
Text("A long text as example")
  .font(.title2).bold()
  .foregroundColor(.pink)
```

Once you have hit upon the right offset amount for the default text size, you might be able to accommodate accessibility variations by making the offset size relative to a base size, e.g.

```
Struct MyView: View {
  @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .title2) var baselineOffset: CGFloat = 3.0

  // and in your body…
  .baselineOffset(baselineOffset)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. Specially with the ScaledMetric for accessibility support.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, you can remove the `HStack` because it is redundant. You can just replace it with brackets `()` to encapsulate the new `Text`, so you can use more modifiers like for setting the width.

The main solution is to use [`baselineOffset(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/baselineoffset(_:)) which means you can offset your image from the baseline of `Text`. Below, we only offset by `1`, but this can be any value you want (including decimal numbers, e.g. `0.99`).

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        (
            Text(Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle"))
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
                .baselineOffset(1)
            +
            Text("A long text as example")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
        )
        .frame(width: 140)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

Bonus: you can move your `foregroundColor(.pink)` modifier after the `Text`s have been combined, so you don't have to duplicate that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works fine! The answer of Scott Matthewman is a bit better because of the ScaledMetric and as I have to support accessibility in my app.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried embedding Image in Text?
`Text("Super star \(Image(systemName: "star"))")`